# IIS7: Setup Integrated Windows Authentication like in IIS6

Tags: authentication, iis-7, windows-authentication

This is for IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 that is not part of an AD domain.  I would like to password protect a website, where people have to enter a username/password (a windows account for example) to view the website.  The website would then use its own authentication method (forms) to handle user accounts and decide whether or not to show member specific pages, etc.

With IIS6, we just disabled anonymous access and enabled integrated windows authentication.  IIS7 behaves differently and when I enter the windows username/password to view the site, the site comes up fine but redirects to the login page.  Once I log in, the site behaves naturally. I need to be able to navigate the site without logging in with the website credentials.

I don't think enabling anonymous access would make sense here since I want access to the website to be password protected (popup username/password dialog when you first navigate to the url).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two-stage authentication is not supported with IIS7 Integrated mode.  Authentication is now modularized, so rather than IIS performing authentication followed by asp.net performing authentication, it all happens at the same time.

You can either:

1. Change the app domain to be in IIS6 classic mode...
2. Follow [this example](http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/) ([old link](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/02/11/IIS-7.0-Two_2D00_Level-Authentication-with-Forms-Authentication-and-Windows-Authentication.aspx)) of how to fake two-stage authentication with IIS7 integrated mode.
3. Use [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) and [mod_auth to provide basic authentication](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/site-authentication-not-using-windows-users/)

Comment: Hi Jim, the link isn't working anymore, are you able to find where the content has gone? perhaps paste it into your answer? Thanks.

Comment: "the link" is probably here: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

Answer (score 69):

To enable the Windows Authentication on IIS7 on Windows 7 machine:

- Go to Control Panel
- Click Programs >> Programs and Features
- Select "Turn Windows Features on or off" from  left side.
- Expand Internet Information Services >> World Wide Web Services >> Security
- Select Windows Authentication and click OK.
- Reset the IIS and Check in IIS now for windows authentication.

Enjoy

Comment: how can I get this to work just using my login name and not require a username/password?

Comment: I also had to do this for my site:  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication

Comment: FWIW/Late googlers: For Windows8: search for "Windows features" in Settings. Then expand Internet information services->World wide web services->Security->Windows authentication One has to restart IISManager for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

So do you want them to get the IE password-challenge box, or should they be directed to your login page and enter their information there? If it's the second option, then you should at least enable Anonymous access to your login page, since the site won't know who they are yet.

If you want the first option, then the login page they're getting forwarded to will need to read the currently logged-in user and act based on that, since they would have had to correctly authenticate to get this far.

Comment: I want them to get the popup dialog to be forced to access the site.  But they will not be logged into the site at that point. They should then be able to navigate the pages on the site and optionally login using the webpage login.

Answer (score -1):

There's another thread elsewhere on Stack with a similar topic and the best solution I've come across is to use the free version of [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/)

Once you've got that installed, follow the steps at the page Titled "HTTP Authentication and Authorization"