# IIS7: How to define that windows authentication is turned on?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

IIS7: How to define that windows authentication is turned on?

I know that [two-stage authentication is not supported with IIS7 Integrated mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436169/iis7-setup-integrated-windows-authentication-like-in-iis6) but I need to define whether windows authentication is turned on to enable spacial windows authenticated features.

Can I define the IIS version **from the ASP .NET code**? 
Can I define that windows authentication is turned on IIS 7 **from the ASP .NET code**?

Comment: Do you need to change from authentication type on runtime (from code) or is single configuration change sufficient?

Comment: I need to change from authentication type on runtime (from code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to share the found solution. To get whether Windows Authentication is is enabled for **current** web application do following:

```
 Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication");
 return windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"];
```

Please note that the code above get effective configuration:

If there is not configuration specified for the web application the setting form the parent web site will be returned. You can find more info about the configuration inheritance here: [Working With Configuration Files in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28WS.10%29.aspx)