# Windows authentication while opening browser

Tags: windows, .htaccess, security, http-authentication

I have a project where the browser should ask for windows authentication while opening any website through http.

Please help me what should i do.I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using IIS as your web server. What you are looking for is called `Windows Integrated Authentication`.

Just follow this answer: [IIS7: Setup Integrated Windows Authentication like in IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436169/iis7-setup-integrated-windows-authentication-like-in-iis6)